# Serializing a complex object ORM Entity dealing with relational entities

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

In ColdFusion 9 I am serializing an ORM entity. When doing this, though, it's missing relational entities.

The `serializeJSON()` method ColdFusion uses to convert complex objects into JSON notation doesn’t seem to work correctly on ORM objects. Any object that had a property that was an array of other objects is not returned when using `serializeJSON()` on ORM objects!

Has anyone tackled this sort of issue before? How did you handle it?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe this may be happening because you have `lazy="true"` on your relationship. I would try either changing that attribute to false, or calling `getAccount()` on the object before serializing. Let me know if that works and I'll post it as the answer.

Comment: Hi Dan, I don't have any issue with getAccount() the problem is with  serializing ORM entities. I need to find a way to iterate 
through all the properties of the entity and build a structure. This is the only way I can see how to resolve this.

Comment: also this is a collection not just one entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved! This is not a bug you have to set remotingFetch to true!  By default it is set to false for properties with one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, or many-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar issues with remote methods and came up with a recursive function that will introspect your CFC and send back the properties you need. You can specify (with attributes on the CFC) which properties you do and don't want to return. Actually, you can do it by "groups" of properties, so you could assign "id" and "name" to the "compact" group and the rest of the properties in your CFC to the "full" group. It will also handle serializing nested components (ORM or otherwise). The other big advantage is that Adobe's serialization methods do not serialize properties from inherited objects. So if you have a parent object, you will not get those properties back when serialized. My toSerializable() method solves that.

Check it out: http://www.justcodefaster.com/blog/2012/07/toserializable-method-for-coldfusion-objects/